# i want to add custom help text below custom attribute

Tags: attributes, custom-options

I added a custom option, say ring size in my product. I want to add a custom help text that will open a PDF in a popup window.  Apparently I cannot use HTML in the title field.

Example:

```
<a href="a.pdf">need help ?</a>
```

Comment: what did you tried and where you want to show that? product page?

Comment: i tried adding html tag in text title field but i figured it shows it as text not html

Answer (score 2):

got to

`app/design/frontend/yortheme/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/types/`

and check for which type you select for custom option and add you condition and text there.

Comment: but can i do it vai observer, i do not want to edit files

Comment: you have to rewrite the custom option template.if you want to do the theme then do it from file and if you creating a module the rewrite template file i thin observer will not help on that

Answer (score 1):

Goto your attribute phtml file. If you have created configurable product, your size attribute file path look like:

app\design\frontend\MyPakage\MyTheme\template\catalog\product\view\type\options\configurable.phtml. Edit the file add some code css and js.

Add code where you want to display

```
<span id="someelem">Help me!</span>
```

Add the below code in the bottom of file.

**JS Code**

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    // More code using $ as alias to jQuery
        var tooltipTimeout;

$("#someelem").hover(function()
                    {tooltipTimeout = setTimeout(showTooltip, 2000);}, 
                    hideTooltip);

function showTooltip()
    {
    var tooltip = $("<div id='tooltip' class='tooltip'>I'm the tooltip!</div>");
    tooltip.appendTo($("#someelem"));
    }

function hideTooltip()
    {
    clearTimeout(tooltipTimeout);
    $("#tooltip").fadeOut().remove();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

**CSS Code**

```
<style>
#someelem
    {
    cursor: pointer;
    }

.tooltip
    {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(130, 150, 200);
    padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
```

Hope this helps!